# How do I use regex to replace with spaces the underscores separating words when the number of words can vary

Tags: regex

I have a number of occurrences of text like this:

```
class="thumbnailtitle">ants_and_mushrooms_aprons-154319855980844358</a>
```

contained in an html page and I want to replace the underscores with spaces. The number of words separated by underscores may vary from zero to many in each occurrence.
There are many other places in the html where underscores occur but it's only where it begins as shown with the `class="thumbnailtitle">` and ends with `</a>` that the changes are to be made.

Is it possible to use regex to do this?

Thanks for any assistance :)

~~Mark

Comment: Are you using `javascript` to do it?

Comment: No, the html page is generated by another tool, one which I have no control over. I have a text processing tool that allows me to use regex, so I planned to use that.

Comment: How do you know what the position of the attr/val will be?

Comment: `class = thumbnailtitle` is a valid html attr/val. Usee a DOM.

Comment: Can you tell me if [`(?:\G(?!\A)|class="thumbnailtitle">)(?:[^_](?!<\/a>))*\K_`](http://regex101.com/r/zK3wZ1/3) in your text editor (replaced with a blank space) works?

Comment: @Sam - probably want to put the assertion ahead of the negative class, or it will match `<` of `</a>` and blow right past it.

Comment: @sin - I don't know what it's position will be ahead of time. I don't have the opportunity to walk the DOM in a regex tool, the only tool available to me - unless you know a way.

Comment: @Sam - no it doesn't. I get no match at all.

Comment: @MarkHightonRidley - A quick solution is you can download [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com), it supports the Find/Replace paradigm using Perl/PCRE compatible regex and macro's.

Comment: @sin That looks like it might do it. A lot of learning for me to do, though!

Comment: Let's consider this question answered, thanks to Sin :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using, but you could adapt this answer for it. I am matching groups and rebuilding them in the replace callback.

You can have this groups by adding matches in between `(` `)`, retrieve them and manipulate as you see fit.

```
t.replace(/(class=.thumbnailtitle..*?>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/gi,
    function(m0,m1,m2,m3) {
        return m1 + m2.replace(/_/g, " ") + m3;
    }
)
```

Comment: In this case, `..*?` is equivalent to `.*?`.

Comment: I'm not using a programming language, I'm using a search replace tool that has a regex function.